# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException Class too Layered?

Tags: vb.net, json.net, response

I'm getting an error when I try to deserialize the following JSON.

Copy this into TextBox2.text:

```
{
    “code” : 200,
    “message" : "success",
    “version" : “2",
    “basket” : 
    {
        “total”: “9.23”,
        “subTotal” : “8.45”,
        “currency” : “USD”,
        “discounts” : [
            {
                “product_id” : 1,
                “description”: “Bud Light 6-pack”,
                “UPC” : “23423423423”,
                “quantity” : 1,
                “price” : “-0.45”
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Class JSON_resultMktBasket
    'This is the response from the mkt basket   - /v2/transaction/transaction_id
    Public code As String
    Public message As String
    Public version As String
    Public basket As mktBasket

End Class

Public Class mktBasket
    'Used by JSON_resultMktBasket
    Public total As String
    Public subtotal As String
    Public currency As String
    Public discounts As ProductDiscounts()

End Class

Public Class ProductDiscounts
    'Used by JSON_resultMktBasket
    Public product_id As String
    Public description As String
    Public UPC As String
    Public quantity As String
    Public price As String
End Class

Private Sub btnMktBasketResponse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMktBasketResponse.Click
    'this is for reading the response when it comes back from the intial store call
    Dim obj2 As JSON_resultMktBasket
    MsgBox(Me.TextBox2.Text)
    'Following line is where i get the exception.......
    obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_resultMktBasket)(Me.TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid property identifier character: “. Path '', line 2, position 0.

Is this due to the fact that I've got a class that includes other classes 2 layers deep?  I don't really know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Rather than posting *part* of a GUI, why not produce a [mcve] in the form of a console app? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: But at the moment, it looks like the problem is that your JSON has curly quotes: `“code”` instead of straight quotes: `"code"`. That's just not valid JSON.

Comment: Thank Jon, I'd never have seen that!  I was copying the sample response from a PPT slide....argh.  That got me farther along.\

Comment: JSON_resultMktBasket is the top object that I'm deserializing but after getting the ogj i can only go one layer into the obj
I can only access code,message,version and basket.
I need to go into mktBasket discounts 
and then into ProductDiscounts()
to get the price value for either ProductDiscounts(0) or ProductDiscounts(1)
Is there a Json syntax for digging into the obj created by
 obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_resultMktBasket)(Me.TextBox2.Text)
 ??